Solving linear-stabilty problem numerically
Consider following coupled equations
$$\sum_nC_{n,(f)}(\theta, \phi , \psi) \partial_\theta^n f + \sum_nC_{n,(g)}(\theta, \phi, \psi) \partial_\theta^n g = \partial_t f (\theta, \phi) $$
$$\sum_nD_{n,(f)}(\theta, \phi , \psi) \partial_\theta^n f + \sum_nD_{n,(g)}(\theta, \phi , \psi) \partial_\theta^n g = \partial_t g (\theta, \phi) $$
Here, $C_{n,(f)}$ is the coefficient which can be a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$ as well as tuning parameter $\psi$. The subscript $n,(f)$ denotes that this coefficient is in front of $n$th order derivative of function $f$.
Depending on the values $\psi$ the solution will either be trivial ( equal to zero) or it will grow exponentially. I would like to find the threshold values of $\psi$ numerically, where this transition occurs.
My first thought was : One can simply write down the FD/FEM scheme and numerically solve above problem for  various values of $\psi$ and find a threshold where we find that solution explodes.
But this does not seem like an elegant solution. And this won't give me the non-trivial solutions (aka eigenfunctions) as well. How should I approach this problem?
I am not that well-versed with this topic. So if you can share th

What do you know about how these coefficients look like? And what values of $n$ do the sums iterate over?

The right way to deal with this kind of problem is convert it to a linear algebra eigenvalue problem, and put it in a standard eigenvalue package.

@WolfgangBangerth, n can be maximum 4.

@MaximUmansky I see what you mean! I can use say FD discretisation and get matrix $M(\theta, \phi)$ and calculate its eigenvalues. But how are these eigenvalues (which would be dependent on discretisation)  related to the eigenvalues of the continuous problem?

@learning_physics If the spatial discretization is implemented correctly (consistent with the underlying PDE's governing the physical system), the discretized system, for sufficiently fine mesh, approximates the properties of the physical system, and this applies to the time response, instabilities growth rates etc. In this case, the physics PDE's are already given in the linearized form, so the discretized system becomes a linear algebra problem.
